# Error during reconcile: "The version could not be reconciled. Invalid network element id : Field is not editable

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, geometric-network, reconcile

While reconciling a child version with the parent version, in a dataset containing Geometric network, the following error was noticed.

Error during reconcile: "The version could not be reconciled. Invalid network element id : Field is not editable "

We work on ArcGIS 10.1 .

Tried to repair the Geometric network and do the reconcile , but to same effect.

What is the core issue behind the error and what is the workaround.

Experts pls advice.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem and there is an ArcGIS **[10.1 SP1 for (Desktop) Geometric Network Reconcile Patch](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/1985)** to resolve it.